# Why won't Flutter mobX store code generate?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation, mobx

I have a mobx store and it's really hit and miss getting my storename.g.dart generated.

The first time, I copied an example from medium and just kept running the generator until eventually it gave code.

The second time, I wrote my own store forgot the abstract keyword. Added it in and it worked.

I thought that was the problem.

Now, third project, I think I have all my code down but it's still not generating. Many actions but no output.

What makes it work or fail? This is my current mobx

```
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

// have this line
// then generate with
// flutter packages pub run build_runner build
// or
// flutter packages pub run build_runner clean; flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

// todo edit this file name
part 'usermodel.g.dart';

class UserModel = UserModelBase with _$UserModel;

abstract class UserModelBase implements Store {
  @observable
  FirebaseUser user;

  @action
  setUser(FirebaseUser u){
    user = u;
  }

  dispose() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Store` is should be used as a mixin.

Do:

```
abstract class Foo with Store {}
```

Don't:

```
abstract class Foo implements Store {
  void dispose() {} 
}
```

Comment: Well, my previous code generation that worked, I also used `implements` and not `with`. I checked the definition and Store is a `class` not a `mixin`. Having said that ... changing `implements` to `with` worked. ‍♂️ ... I don't understand how it worked, but thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, I get it! In the previous example I copied, in MobX 0.1.4, `Store` was an `abstract class Store {}`

On my third try, in MobX 0.2.0, `Store` became a
```mixin Store {
  void dispose() {}
}
```
That explains it.

Comment: To be fair, I'm the one that made that braking change on mobx. So that's my fault here haha

Comment: Hahaha. I appreciate the reply and help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an answer in addition to the helpful one @Remi Posted.

When I copied the example, I had copied the entries in pubspec.yaml and it specified mobx 0.1.4 which defined `Store` as an

`abstract class Store {}`

However, when I did my third project, I added `mobx:` without the version and it became 0.2.0 which defined `Store` as a

```
mixin Store {
  void dispose() {}
}
```

Which then required the change of keyword `implements` to `with`. Thanks for figuring that out!